# Serilog, .NET 7, error NU1605 ("detected package downgrade") and Microsoft.NETCore.Targets

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, serilog

In a .NET 7 project, I use Serilog (the latest [`Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File v3.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File/3.0.0)) and get a bunch of errors `NU1605` when trying to compile the project with `dotnet publish`:

```
Agent.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.File 3.2.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO (>= 4.3.0) 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> System.IO (>= 4.1.0)
Agent.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.File 3.2.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0) 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1)
Agent.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Handles from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.File 3.2.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.3.0) 
Agent.csproj : error NU1605:  Agent -> Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File 3.0.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile 3.3.0 -> Serilog.Sinks.File 3.2.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> System.Runtime.Handles (>= 4.0.1)
```

Upon some digging, I've found that adding the following to my `.csproj` file solves the problem:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="5.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

However, the [`Microsoft.NETCore.Targets`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Targets/6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7) package was stopped being updated at `v6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7`. Apparently, it has been deprecated, see the ["Delete Microsoft.NETCore.Targets package"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/52261) issue.

To troubleshoot it further, I've enabled ["repeatable package restores using a lock file"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/) (the right thing to do for CI builds anyway). Here's what I see in my `packages.lock.json`:

```json
      "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile": {
        "type": "Transitive",
        "resolved": "3.3.0",
        "contentHash": "2lT5X1r3GH4P0bRWJfhA7etGl8Q2Ipw9AACvtAHWRUSpYZ42NGVyHoVs2ALBZ/cAkkS+tA4jl80Zie144eLQPg==",
        "dependencies": {
          "Serilog.Sinks.File": "3.2.0",
          "System.IO": "4.1.0",
          "System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives": "4.0.1",
          "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
          "System.Text.Encoding.Extensions": "4.0.11"
        }
      },

// ...

      "System.IO": {
        "type": "Transitive",
        "resolved": "4.1.0",
        "contentHash": "3KlTJceQc3gnGIaHZ7UBZO26SHL1SHE4ddrmiwumFnId+CEHP+O8r386tZKaE6zlk5/mF8vifMBzHj9SaXN+mQ==",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1",
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Targets": "1.0.1",
          "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
          "System.Text.Encoding": "4.0.11",
          "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11"
        }
      },
      "System.IO.FileSystem": {
        "type": "Transitive",
        "resolved": "4.0.1",
        "contentHash": "IBErlVq5jOggAD69bg1t0pJcHaDbJbWNUZTPI96fkYWzwYbN6D9wRHMULLDd9dHsl7C2YsxXL31LMfPI1SWt8w==",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1",
          "Microsoft.NETCore.Targets": "1.0.1",
          "System.IO": "4.1.0",
          "System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives": "4.0.1",
          "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
          "System.Runtime.Handles": "4.0.1",
          "System.Text.Encoding": "4.0.11",
          "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11"
        }
      },
```

Given that `Microsoft.NETCore.Targets` has been deprecated, **what is the proper strategy to solve this problem**, which I believe can be pretty common these days, now that .NET 3.x LTS is nearing EOL and .NET has been released?

Also, what is the magic behind the current workaround, provided that `Microsoft.NETCore.Targets` is basically just an empty package, with a zero-length `lib\netstandard1.0\_._` file inside it?

Comment: A follow-up on GH: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3044#issuecomment-1316108587

Comment: And this GH comment answers my question about what magic is behind the fix: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47110#issuecomment-764887101

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer at least to this part:

> what is the magic behind the current workaround, provided that
> `Microsoft.NETCore.Targets` is basically just an empty package, with a
> zero-length `lib\netstandard1.0\_._` file inside it?

Here is [a great explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47110#issuecomment-764887101) of how the actual fix works. Essentially, `Microsoft.NETCore.Targets` is an empty package from v3.1.0 and on, and the only purpose of it is to override and prevent loading any of its earlier versions, like those from .NET Core 1.x or 2.x:

> The older version had a runtime.json which caused package downgrades

Answer (score 1):

I use serilog and just updated to .net 7 myself.  Didn't have any issues but I don't use that file.  Just these:

```
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.4.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Just noticed that Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File uses the deprecated RollingFile sink.

Comment: Tks! TBH I only use [`AddFile`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file#:~:text=.AddFile) one-liner from `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File`. Has `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` itself been deprecated?

Comment: I think this nuget just wrapped up a few core serilog nugets and made it a little easier to setup.  ie one line.  I use the configuration nuget, the setup is read from your appsettings.json. https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration

Comment: IN my case, i explicitly try to build/publish using the .net 6.0 framework and i still get that error. How would i go about ignoring those as the code builds in the VS